# PHP get nodes value with nested nodes XML

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have a xml file:

```
<Epo>
<Doc upd="add">
<Fld name="IC"><Prg><Sen>A01B1/00 <Cmt>(1585, 779)</Cmt></Sen></Prg></Fld>
<Fld name="CC"><Prg><Sen>A01B1/00 <Cmt>(420, 54%)</Cmt>;</Sen><Sen>B25G1/102 <Cmt>(60, 8%)</Cmt>;</Sen><Sen>A01B1/02 <Cmt>(47, 6%)</Cmt></Sen></Prg></Fld></Doc>
<Doc upd="add">
<Fld name="IC"><Prg><Sen>A01B1/02 <Cmt>(3847, 1718)</Cmt></Sen></Prg></Fld>
<Fld name="CC"><Prg><Sen>A01B1/02 <Cmt>(708, 41%)</Cmt>;</Sen><Sen>A01B1/022 <Cmt>(347, 20%)</Cmt>;</Sen><Sen>A01B1/028 <Cmt>(224, 13%)</Cmt></Sen></Prg></Fld></Doc>
</Epo>
```

I want to get node value, for example : A01B1/00 (1585, 779) - A01B1/00 (420, 54%); B25G1/102 (60, 8%); A01B1/02 (47, 6%)
Then formating them into table's column. how can I do that?
My code:

```
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $doc->load('test.xml'); //IPCCPC-epoxif-201905
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $titles = $xpath->query('//Doc/Fld'); 
        foreach ($titles as $title){
            echo $title->nodeValue ."<hr>";
            }
?>
```

I cannot separate evrey node. Please help me.

Comment: If that is exactly the contents of your XML file, then it is missing a root node.  All XML documents must only have 1 root - this has 2 `<Doc>` nodes.

Comment: Sorry for my bad, I edited root node

Comment: @HàmLouis, maybe `$title->textContent` (instead of `$title->nodeValue`) is what you are looking for

Comment: It still show all value, but I want to separate it into 4 value, how to I get it? I tried to use item(0), item(1) but it do not works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to split it down to fetch all the various levels of content, but I think the main problem was just getting the current node text without the child elements text content.  Using DOMDocument, the [`nodeValue`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodevalue) is the same as `textContent` which (from the manual)...

> textContent The text content of this node and its descendants.

Using DOMDocument isn't the easiest to use when just accessing a relatively simple hierarchy and requires you to continually make calls (in this case) to `getElementsByTagName()` to fetch the enclosed elements, the following source shows how you can get at each part of the document using this method...

```
foreach ( $doc->getElementsByTagName("Doc") as $item )    {
    echo "upd=".$item->getAttribute("upd").PHP_EOL;
    foreach ( $item->getElementsByTagName("Fld") as $fld )  {
        echo "name=".$fld->getAttribute("name").PHP_EOL;
        foreach ( $fld->getElementsByTagName("Sen") as $sen )  {
            echo trim($sen->firstChild->nodeValue) ." cmt = ".
                $sen->getElementsByTagName("Cmt")[0]->firstChild->nodeValue.PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Using the SimpleXML API can however give a simpler solution.  Each level of the hierarchy is accessed using object notation, and so `->Doc` is used to access the Doc elements off the root node, and the `foreach()` loops just work off that.  You can also see that using just the element name (`$sen->Cmt`) will give you just the text content of that node and not the descendants (although you have to cast it to a string to get it's value from the object) ...

```
$doc = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");

foreach ( $doc->Doc as $docElemnt )    {
    echo "upd=".(string)$docElemnt['upd'].PHP_EOL;
    foreach ( $docElemnt->Fld as $fld )    {
        echo "name=".(string)$fld['name'].PHP_EOL;
        foreach ( $fld->Prg->Sen as $sen )    {
            echo trim((string)$sen)."=".trim((string)$sen->Cmt).PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, It works perfectly. Can I have one more question, I want to search a node value by $key from <form action> then return values of node that are same level with the first node I search. Example: <Doc><Fld name="IC">ABC</Fld><Fld name="CC">123</Fld></Doc>. How can I do that?

Comment: If you want to select just those `<Fld>` elements, then you can use an XPath expression such as `$doc->xpath("//Doc/Fld[@name='CC']")`